# Prevent or work around Git for Windows updater changing git binary precedence in PATH

Tags: powershell, git-for-windows

I have PowerShell scripts on my machine which call git, i.e. Git for Windows. I also have Cygwin installed, which has a git binary in the main bin folder which it adds to the PATH.

When I'm calling git from these scripts, I want them to use the normal Git for Windows binary. (The cygwin binary won't work, it thinks unchanged files are changed when running "git status --porcelain," I suspect owing to something different about line endings in its global config. That's beside the point.) As a result, I set my PATH to have the Git for Windows binary folder appear before the Cygwin bin folder. This is perfect, the correct binary gets called by scripts and Cygwin can continue existing unperturbed.

The problem is that every time Git for Windows auto-updates, it edits the PATH to remove its entry, then re-add its entry, effectively moving its entry to the end - behind Cygwin in precedence. My script fails a few times until I remember I need to go edit the PATH again.

Is there a way to get the Git for Windows updater to leave the PATH alone, a better way to get the PowerShell scripts to use the correct git binary (without hardcoding the path, the script must work on all developers' machines), or some other workaround?

Comment: Does `Get-Command git -All` list both versions?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen oh it does - and the Cygwin conveniently shows up as versionless, 0.0.0.0 which seems useful. I'm guessing there's a way to choose the binary based on that output? I'm very much new to PowerShell.

Comment: Would uninstalling the Cygwin git help? You say that Cygwin git will not work.

Comment: @lit it works fine for its actual intended purposes within Cygwin, it just doesn't work when called from elsewhere (which is to be expected.)

Comment: The Cygwin bin directory should not be in the PATH until after a Cygwin shell is started. Are you wanting to run git for Windows from a Cygwin shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Get-Command` to resolve both binaries, then use `Set-Alias` to hide whichever one takes precedence behind the one you need:

```
$gitForWindows = Get-Command git -All |Where-Object Source -notlike *cygwin* |Select-Object -First 1
Set-Alias git -Value $gitForWindows.Source
```

Comment: When I try this, the first line works as expected (prunes the list down to the desired version), but Set-Alias errors out saying there's no such -Definition parameter (and I don't see one in the docs.) Omitting the -Definition parameter it just sets the alias definition to "git.exe" not the full path.

Comment: My bad, answer updated :)

Comment: On the off chance they have a third git binary on the PATH, may want to pipe add `| Select-Object -First 1` after `where-object`

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Good suggestion

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a workaround using a PowerShell profile, but if you add:

```
$env:PATH = 'C:\Path\To\Git\For\Windows\bin;' + $env:PATH
```

to one of your `$profile` locations, this will effectively guarantee that the **Git for Windows** binaries always come before **cygwin** does. Note that this doesn't workaround the issue for processes launched outside of PowerShell or PowerShell sessions started with `-NoProfile`.

You can see your profile locations by checking the following variables:

```
$profile.AllUsersAllHosts
$profile.AllUsersCurrentHost
$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
$profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
```

---

Alternatively, you could bake the `$env:PATH` mutation into your scripts which need it, if you can't or don't want to use the profile approach. The point is that modifying the PATH variable effectively sidesteps this issue.

You could also set the `git` alias as performed in [@MathiasR.Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70673195/584676) inside of one of the profiles as well, to prevent having to do this in every script.

Comment: Ah, I do usually launch this script from a convenience batch script that uses -NoProfile, but I can change my launch method to running the PS script directly and this would work.

Comment: You should also be able to set the envvar in the batch script too, with `set PATH="C:\Path\To\Git\For\Windows\bin;%PATH%"` before running your PS script.